# Display ruby program in browser

Tags: ruby, browser, terminal

I am aware that there are some simliar answers. However, I have not found any that have exactly answered my question.

I have written a program with ruby (orange.rb) which runs in the terminal. It is an interactive and visual program which is shared bellow. On my portfolio, I would like to share this program and make it usable in the visitor's browser. How can I do so?

Thank you.

```
class OrangeTree

  def initialize
    @age = 0
    @orangeCount = 0
    @height = 0
    puts "Welcome to the orange-tree game. You can leave the game at any time by typing 'exit'. "
    puts "Would you like to plant an orange tree?"
    getFirstInput
  end

  def getFirstInput
    @firstInput = gets.downcase.chomp
    if @firstInput == 'yes'
      puts "Congratulations. You have planted an orange tree"
      plantTree
      puts "There are still no oranges. Would you like to wait a few more years?"
      waitFewYears?
    elsif @firstInput == 'no'
      puts "Goodbye"
      exit
    elsif @firstInput == "exit"
      puts "Goodbye"
      exit
    else
      puts "Please type 'yes', 'no', or 'exit'"
      getFirstInput
    end
  end

  def waitFewYears?
    @input = gets.downcase.chomp
    if @input == 'yes'
      puts "Here you go"
      @age = 4
      drawTree
      orangeGrowth
      countTheOranges
    elsif @input == 'no'
      puts "Gooybye"
      exit
    elsif @input == 'exit'
      puts "Goodbye"
      exit
    else
      puts "Please type 'yes', 'no', or 'exit'"
      waitFewYears?
    end
  end

  def waitOneYear?
    puts "Do you want to wait another year?"
    @wantsToWait = gets.downcase.chomp
    if @wantsToWait == "yes"
      puts
      oneYearPasses
    elsif @wantsToWait == "no"
      puts "Goodbye"
      exit
    elsif @wantsToWait == "exit"
      puts "Goodbye"
      exit
    else
      puts "Please type 'yes', 'no', or 'exit'"
      waitOneYear?
    end
  end

  def oneYearPasses
    @orangeCount = 0
    @tree.replace(@originalTree)
    puts "Another year has passed"
    @age = @age + 1
    puts "The tree is #{@age.to_s} years old"
    @height = @height + 1
    puts "The tree is #{@height} ft tall"
    orangeGrowth
    countTheOranges
    pickAnOrange?
  end

  def orangeGrowth
    @orangeCount = @orangeCount + @age - 3
    i = 0
    while i < @orangeCount
      @tree["_"] = ""
      i = i + 1
    end
    puts @tree
  end

  def countTheOranges
    if @orangeCount < 1
      puts "There are still no oranges"
    elsif @orangeCount == 1
      puts "There is one orange on the tree"
      pickAnOrange?
    else
    puts "There are #{@orangeCount} oranges on the tree"
    pickAnOrange?
    end
  end

  def pickAnOrange?
    puts "Would you like to pick an orange?"
    @wantsApple = gets.downcase.chomp
    if @orangeCount > 0
      if @wantsApple == "yes"
        @orangeCount = @orangeCount - 1
        @tree[""] = "_"
        puts @tree
        puts "That was delicious"
        if @orangeCount < 1
          puts "There are no more oranges left"
        elsif @orangeCount == 1
          puts "There is one more orange left"
          pickAnOrange?
        else
          puts "There are #{@orangeCount} oranges left"
          pickAnOrange?
        end
      elsif @wantsApple == "no"
        puts "Alright, hombre"
      elsif @wantsApple == "exit"
        puts "Goodbye"
        exit
      else
        puts "Please type 'yes', 'no', or 'exit'"
        pickAnOrange?
      end
    end
    waitOneYear?
  end

  def plantTree
    puts <<-'EOF'


                  \ }{
                   }{{
                   }}{
                   {{}
              , -=-~{ .-^- _
              ejm        `}
                    {

    EOF


  def drawTree
  @tree = <<-'EOF'

                \/ |    |/
              \/ / \||/  /_/___/_
               \/   |/ \/
          _\_\_\    |  /_____/_
                 \  | /          /
        __ _-----`  |{,-----------~
                  \ }{
                   }{{
                   }}{
                   {{}
             , -=-~{ .-^- _
        ejm        `}
                    {

      EOF
      @originalTree = <<-'EOF'

                    \/ |    |/
                  \/ / \||/  /_/___/_
                   \/   |/ \/
              _\_\_\    |  /_____/_
                     \  | /          /
            __ _-----`  |{,-----------~
                      \ }{
                       }{{
                       }}{
                       {{}
                 , -=-~{ .-^- _
            ejm        `}
                        {

          EOF

  end

  end



end

tree = OrangeTree.new
```

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something akin to [Ruby Fiddle](http://rubyfiddle.com) that runs your script?

Comment: @ForeverZer0, yes I am. I'm using repl.it right now, but it would be cool to use my "own" terminal

Comment: @lacostenycoder: "Ruby doesn't run in the browser." – That is simply not true. Ruby is a programming language. It doesn't "run" anywhere. Ruby *programs* run, and they most certainly can run in the browser. There is a Ruby implementation called Opal that compiles Ruby to ECMAScript which can be run in a browser. There used to be an experimental version of Firefox that ran Ruby natively. There used to be a demo by Microsoft running a mixed Ruby-Python-VisualBasic-ECMAScript program in the browser using IronRuby, IronPython, proprietary DLR-based implementations of VisualBasic and ECMAScript, …

Comment: … DLR, and Silverlight / Moonlight. You can use Emscripten to compile any C and C++ code (thus also including YARV and MRuby) into ECMAScript to run in the browser, which can then interpret Ruby code. There used to be a native ECMAScript implementation of the YARV bytecode VM in the browser called HotRuby. There used to be a flash-based implementation of the YARV bytecode VM called RedSun. You can run JRuby or TruffleRuby in a Java applet in the browser.

Comment: @lacostenycoder ????? I simply commented to ask if was similar to linked site. Nothing about heredoc, indentation, etc.   ?